# Rx code blocks UI thread?

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I'm experiencing Reactive Programming (Rx) and one of its interesting feature is subscribing and observing on different threads. But here somehow it blocks the UI thread. Technically I don't have any method returning Task (async method), so here I'm trying to mimic a long process with `Thread.Sleep`:

```
IEnumerable<Item> _search(string searchText)
{
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        //return result by querying ...
        //...
        return someResult;
}
```

I have a ViewModel class like this:

```
public class ViewModel {
   public ViewModel(){
       //this SubscribeOn may not be necessary but I just try it here for sure
       SearchTextStream.SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
                       .ObserveOn(DispatcherScheduler.Current)
                       .Subscribe(searchText => {
                          var items = _search(searchText);
                 }, ex => {
                    //handle error
            });
   }
   public string SearchText
   {
        get
        {
            return _searchText.FirstAsync().Wait();
        }
        set
        {
            _searchText.OnNext(value);
        }
   }
   ISubject<string> _searchText = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
   public IObservable<string> SearchTextStream
   {
        get
        {
            return _searchText.AsObservable().DistinctUntilChanged();
        }
   }
}
```

Actually without using `Thread.Sleep`, I can still see it blocks the UI but not very obvious, so I just use it to make it more obvious. As I said, the scenario here is that I have just a normal method without any task or async. It may be a long-running method. Using with RX, I don't know which should be done to make it behave like async (as when using a `Task.Run`)?

I'm testing on a `WPF` application if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `_search(searchText)` on the `DispatcherScheduler.Current` scheduler - and hence, with the `Thread.Sleep` you're blocking the UI.

You really should make `_search` return an observable.

```
IObservable<IEnumerable<Item>> _search(string searchText)
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    //return result by querying ...
    //...
    return Observable.Return(new [] { new Item() });
}
```

Now the constructor should look like this:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    SearchTextStream
        .ObserveOn(System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.Default)
        .SelectMany(searchText => _search(searchText))
        .ObserveOnDispatcher()
        .Subscribe(items =>
        {
            /* do something with `items` */
        }, ex =>
        {
            //handle error
        });
}
```

Comment: I think this is not exactly matching my code requirement. Each time search is performed, a block of `IEnumerable<Item>` result is returned. This is what like a black-box (as detailed by the `_search` method). So if I could change it, I would use `Task` here.

Comment: I'm trying to use Rx to deal with this scenario instead of using such as `Task.Run(() => _search(...))` which can actually put `_search` on a non-UI-blocking thread.

Comment: @Hopeless - I've updated the answer. In my opinion Rx is more powerful than Tasks. You should find that the above code is running on a non-UI thread.

Comment: I've changed code to what you suggested but still it blocking the UI. If possible please create a small wpf app with just a TextBox and with all the code I posted here, you'll see that it can hardly work the way I want. In fact I've myself tried various approaches after asking this question, but still no luck.

Comment: @Hopeless - I missed adding a `.ObserveOn(System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.Default)`. It works now.

Comment: yes it works now, thanks for the code. But really I don't understand why it does not involve the `SubscribeOn`. I thought that all the code not involving UI should run on the thread indicated by `SubscribeOn`, while before we start showing data to UI, the `ObserveOn` should be used to switch the thread context. Looks like the sequence transformation (such as by using `SelectMany`) is still running in UI thread (as by default when we not using any `ObserveOn` explicitly)?

Comment: my extra question involves the usage of `SubscribeOn` and `ObserveOn`, when using this but not that? I'll accept your answer soon btw.

Comment: @Hopeless - You only rarely need to use `SubscribeOn` - it it useful for when there is a deadlock during subscription - this is the code that returns the `IDisposable` when you call `Subscribe`. Generally `ObserveOn` is what you'll use - it can be put anywhere in your observable pipeline.